# Spring and Jackson Json: serialising two different sets of fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I've a Classified interface, annotated with @JsonAutoDetect with Visibility.NONE, so I can pick individual getters to be serialized with the @JsonSerialize annotation

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public interface Classified {

    @JsonSerialize
    String getModel();
```

Until here there is no problem, and when I return Classified with @ResponseBody annotation, from my @Controller, it works returning the expected JSON:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/classified/{idClassified}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public final Classified getClassified(@PathVariable final int idClassified) {
```

However when I return a List of Classifieds, I would like to return a smaller set of getters, while with the following signature, obviously it returns all marked getters:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/classified", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public final List<Classified> searchClassified(@RequestParam final int idBrand,
    @RequestParam final String priceMax, @RequestParam final int page) {
```

I don't know how to return a smaller subset of Classified getters in each item of the list.

Answer (score 1):

> "return a smaller set of getters"

If you mean reduce the number of items in the list, change the business logic in the controller's searchClassified method.

If you mean reduce the number of available public getter methods on each item, you could create a interface that only implements a subset of the original items getters, and return a list of them instead.

Comment: Yes, sorry for being not clear, I mean the second "reduce the number of available public getter methods on each item". I will try today, thank you!

Comment: I like you solution, is simple and straightforward, while I'm still trying to understand the other one, and I've posted a new question about it.  I had an answer, but I still can't figure it out. The trouble is that, unfortunately, this solution, doesn't work, even if I'm returning a List of the ClassifiedPublic interface, in the JSON there are all properties, including private ones, probably because Spring finds them with reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Check out "[filtering properties](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html)", which lists multiple ways to change what gets serialized. I would guess that Json Views might be the easiest one; could use one smaller view, and then default "all" mode when no view is defined (default is then to serialize all properties).

Comment: I actually went back to this problem today. Json Views is an interesting concept, however, the objectMapper is called by Spring, so I don't know how to tell to render a particular view, [after reading here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews).

Comment: I actually [posted another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793689/spring-and-jacksonjson-serialising-different-fields-with-views) about how to use these views. After reading the documentation I don't know how to use them. Did you actually use them with Spring? Thank you

Comment: No, I use JAX-RS (Jersey) mostly, so I only have second-hand knowledge of Spring MVC