# Spring and JacksonJson, serialising different fields with views

Tags: json, spring, serialization, spring-mvc, jackson

In a [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578081/spring-and-jackson-json-serialising-two-different-sets-of-fields), I asked about, how to serialise two different sets of fields using JacksonJson and Spring.

My use case is the typical Controller mapping with `@ResponseBody` annotation returning directly a particular object or collections of objects, that are then rendered with JacksonJson whenever the client adds `application/json` in the `Accept` header.

I had two answers, the first one suggests to return different interfaces with a different getter list, the second suggests to use Json Views.

I don't have problems to understand the first way, however, for the second, after reading the documentation on [`JacksonJsonViews`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews), I don't know how to implement it with Spring.

To stay with the example, I would declare three stub classes, inside the class Views:

```
// View definitions:
public class Views {
    public static class Public { }
    public static class ExtendedPublic extends PublicView { }
    public static class Internal extends ExtendedPublicView { }
}
```

Then I've to declare the classes mentioned:

```
public class PublicView { }   
public class ExtendedPublicView { }
```

Why on earth they declare empty static classes and external empty classes, I don't know. I understand that they need a "label", but then the static members of Views would be enough. And it's not that `ExtendedPublic` extends `Public`, as it would be logical, but they are in fact totally unrelated.

And finally the bean will specify with annotation the view or list of views:

```
//changed other classes to String for simplicity and fixed typo 
//in classname, the values are hardcoded, just for testing
public class Bean {
    // Name is public
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    String name = "just testing";

    // Address semi-public
    @JsonView(Views.ExtendedPublic.class)
    String address = "address";

    // SSN only for internal usage
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    String ssn = "32342342";
}
```

Finally in the Spring Controller, I've to think how to change the original mapping of my test bean:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bean") 
@ResponseBody
public final Bean getBean() {
    return new Bean();
}
```

It says to call:

```
//or, starting with 1.5, more convenient (ObjectWriter is reusable too)
objectMapper.viewWriter(ViewsPublic.class).writeValue(out, beanInstance);
```

So I have an `ObjectMapper` instance coming out of nowhere and an `out` which is not the servlet typical `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();`, but is an instance of `JsonGenerator` and that can't be obtained with the new operator. So I don't know how to modify the method, here is an incomplete try:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bean")
@ResponseBody
public final Bean getBean() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonGenerator out; //how to create?
    objectMapper.viewWriter(Views.Public.class).writeValue(out, new Bean());
    return ??; //what should I return?
}
```

So I would like to know if anybody had success using `JsonView` with Spring and how he/she did. The whole concept seems interesting, but the documentation seems lacking, also the example code is missing.

If it's not possible I will just use interfaces extending each others. Sorry for the long question.

Comment: Why are you trying to do the JSON yourself?  The HttpMessageConverter that are setup to use Jackson should convert it automatically.

Comment: @chrislovecnm, in my simple example, I simply return the Object or Collection with ResponseBody annotation and Spring does all "behind the scenes". And here is the problem, since it does it "secretly", I don't know how to pass it parameters (in my case the Views.Public.class) to change its behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answers by @igbopie and @chrislovecnm, I've put together an annotation driven solution:

```
@Controller
public class BookService
{
    @RequestMapping("/books")
    @ResponseView(SummaryView.class)
    public @ResponseBody List<Book> getBookSummaries() {}

    @RequestMapping("/books/{bookId}")
    public @ResponseBody Book getBook(@PathVariable("bookId") Long BookId) {}
}
```

Where `SummaryView` is annotated on the `Book` model like so:

```
@Data
class Book extends BaseEntity
{
    @JsonView(SummaryView.class)
    private String title;
    @JsonView(SummaryView.class)
    private String author;
    private String review;

    public static interface SummaryView extends BaseView {}
}

@Data
public class BaseEntity
{
    @JsonView(BaseView.class)
    private Long id;    
}

public interface BaseView {}
```

A custom `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` is then wired into Spring MVC's context to detect the `@ResponseView` annotation, and apply the Jackson view accordingly.

I've supplied full code [over on my blog](http://martypitt.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/custom-json-views-with-spring-mvc-and-jackson/).

Comment: Nice solution! The annotation driven solution looks really neat.

Comment: This is a great solution, however I didn't want to annotate every field in every class to exclude just a couple of fields. So I extended your annotation approach with @ResponseMixinFilters which provides 2 arrays (entities and filter classes) and then do mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(entity,filter) in ViewAndFilterAwareJsonMessageConverter.

Answer (score 4):

You need to manually wire in the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.  In spring 3.1 you are able to use the mvc xml tags like the following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
    <mvc:message-converter>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

It is pretty ugly to not use spring 3.1, it will save you about 20 lines of xml.  The mvc:annotation tag does ALOT.

You will need to wire in the object mapper with the correct view writer.  I have noticed recently the using a @Configuration class can make complicated wiring like this a lot easier.  Use a @Configuration class and create a @Bean with your MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter, and wire the reference to that bean instead of the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter above.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer. However, I'm very far from understanding what I should do. I am using Spring 3.0.6 and I'm already using `mvc:annotation-driven`, I've added `mvc:message-converter` as suggested. However, I get "Element 'mvc:annotation-driven' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty." Then you say "wire the object mapper with the correct view writer", this probably mean a call similar to this: `objectMapper.viewWriter(Views.Public.class)` and I don't know where and how to obtain a reference to objectMapper.

Comment: Then what you say with "I have noticed ..." is it an alternative solution? In practice the bean will be autowired by the AOP @Configuration tag, with a MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter, and I name the variable as I like an Spring will find it? Then I've to tell something about the views, how to do? And how to differentiate them? I've to set something in every object?

Comment: @stivlo you need to use Spring 3.1 to use the mvc:message-converter tag.  Also I am not familiar JacksonJsonViews ...

Comment: Thank you Chris, so I will try later again to experiment on this area... for now I will simply return all properties, since I've some other urgent services to deliver. In case I discover something later, I will share.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! I had a very similar problem and your suggestion solved it. Ain't spring grand...

Answer (score 2):

I've manage to solve the problem this way:

- Create custom abstract class to contain the json response object:

```java
public abstract AbstractJson<E>{
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private E responseObject;

    public E getResponseObject() {
        return responseObject;
    }
    public void setResponseObject(E responseObject) {
        this.responseObject = responseObject;
    }
}
```

- Create a class for each visibility (just to mark the response):

```java
public class PublicJson<E> extends AbstractJson<E> {}
public class ExtendedPublicJson<E> extends AbstractJson<E> {}
public class InternalJson<E> extends AbstractJson<E> {}
```

- Change your method declaration:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bean")
    @ResponseBody
    public final PublicJson<Bean> getBean() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
         return new PublicJson(new Bean());
    }
```

- Create customs MessageConverter:

```java
public class PublicJsonMessageConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter{

    public PublicApiResponseMessageConverter(){
        super();
        org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper objMapper=new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
        objMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
        objMapper.setSerializationConfig(objMapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.Public.class));
        this.setObjectMapper(objMapper);
    }

     public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
         if(clazz.equals(PublicJson.class)){
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

}

public class ExtendedPublicJsonMessageConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter{

    public ExtendedPublicJsonMessageConverter(){
        super();
        org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper objMapper=new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
        objMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
        objMapper.setSerializationConfig(objMapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.ExtendedPublic.class));
        this.setObjectMapper(objMapper);
    }

     public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
         if(clazz.equals(ExtendedPublicJson.class)){
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

}

public class InternalJsonMessageConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter{

    public InternalJsonMessageConverter(){
        super();
        org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper objMapper=new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
        objMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
        objMapper.setSerializationConfig(objMapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.Internal.class));
        this.setObjectMapper(objMapper);
    }

     public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
         if(clazz.equals(Internal.class)){
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

}
```

- Add the following to your xml:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="PublicJsonMessageConverter"></bean>
        <bean class="ExtendedPublicJsonMessageConverter"></bean>
        <bean class="InternalJsonMessageConverter"></bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

That's it! I had to update to spring 3.1 but that's all. I use the responseObject to send more info about the json call but you can override more methods of the MessageConverter to be completely transparent. I hope someday spring include an annotation for this.

Hope this helps!